# TFS powershell task to run docker-compose fails

Tags: docker, tfs, docker-compose, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm using TFS2017.1 on-prem with Windows 2016. In my build definition, I have a PowerShell task that simply runs a docker-compose.yml file. When I execute my build definition, this task fails stating that:

```
##[error]Creating service1 ...
```

However, if I run this in PowerShell console on the build machine, it works without any issues.

```
docker-compose -f "docker-compose.yml" up
```

Is it a known bug or I'm missing something.

Comment: Are you using Linux containers or Windows containers?

Comment: Windows container from Microsoft Windows server core image.

Answer (score 0):

When you run docker-compose, first it tries to create a network and proceeds with the container creation. The error you are seeing is, because of the network creation failure. It's knows as `HNS` issue.
Go through these links, It might work for you.

https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/750

https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1960

Comment: It creates the container eventually. It's just the first statement which is an error.

Comment: can you try `docker network create test_network` on your TFS agent,  if it does not work then its an `HNS` issue, and the error you see might be probably because of this.

Comment: I tried this command and it returned error stating that
`Error response from daemon: plugin not found`